# How to group nodes in Neo4j after they are created?

Tags: neo4j

Imagine a huge graph of users each with one attribute called email. Now imagine I have to group those that use gmail under one group called "google_mail", and those that use "yahoo" into a group called "yahoo_mail".

How do I traverse the graph that is disconnected (no root node to go visit each user node and not every user is connected (i.e. we could have completely disjointed graphs of users). I want to avoid loading all those users into memory. Is this possible?

Comment: Are your users connected to nodes likes GoogleGroup, YahooGroup? (i.e : user -> IS_MEMBER_OF -> GoogleGroup )

Comment: Not a lot of details here, but if you don't have an index that can give you all users you'll have to do `START n=node(*)` then in a WHERE filter for something that lets you know that they are users.  If you're using Neo4J 2.0 you could use a CASE expression to get the group, otherwise return just the IDs of the users and then possibly pull up users in batches and do what you need to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Neo4j 2.0 there is a new feature called labels which seems to be a good fit for your use case, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/graphdb-neo4j-labels.html.

To assign all nodes having an email containing "gmail" a `GoogleMail` label you might use:

```
START n=node(*)
WHERE n.email =~ '.*@gmail.com'
SET n :GoogleMail

START n=node(*)
WHERE n.email =~ '.*@yahoo.com'
SET n :Yahoo
```

Be aware that depending on your graph size you might use `LIMIT` and `SKIP` to apply the change not in a single huge transaction.

To get a list of all gmail users:

```
MATCH (n:GoogleMail) RETURN n
```